# Check if a process is still running

Tags: python, linux, bash, process, psutil

I have the following problem:

I need my Python script run a bash script. In case the bash script is running more than let's say 10 seconds, I need to kill it. This is what I have so far:

```
cmd = ["bash", "script.sh", self.get_script_path()]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)

time.sleep(10)  # process running here...

procinfo = psutil.Process(process.pid)
children = procinfo.children(recursive=True)
for child in children:
    os.kill(child.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

The thing I am afraid of is this scenario: The bash script finishes in 1 second, frees its PID and the system passes the PID to another process. After 10 seconds, I kill the PID which I think it belongs to my script but it is not true and I kill some other process. The script needs to be run as root because I require `chroot` in it.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the subprocess was created without `shell=True` then you should be able to simply use [`process.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill). Otherwise, refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using `psutil` I suggest you replace the calls to the `subprocess` module with calls to [`psutil.Popen`](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Popen). This class has the same interface of `subprocess.Popen` but provides all the functionality of `psutil.Process`.

Also note that **the `psutil` library pre-emptively checks for PID reuse already**, at least for a number of methods including `terminate` and `kill` (just read the [documentation for `Process`](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Popen)).

This means that the following code:

```
cmd = ["bash", "script.sh", self.get_script_path()]
process = psutil.Popen(cmd)

time.sleep(10)  # process running here...

children = process.children(recursive=True)
for child in children:
    child.terminate()   # try to close the process "gently" first
    child.kill()
```

Note that the documentation for `children` says:

> **children(recursive=False)**
>
> Return the children of this process as a list of `Process` objects, **preemptively checking whether PID has been reused.**

In summary this means that:

1. When you call `children` the `psutil` library checks that you want the children of the correct process and not one that happen to have the same pid
2. When you call `terminate` or `kill` the library makes sure that you are killing your child process and not a random process with the same pid.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [`timeout`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) command is perfect for you. From the doc page:

> ### Synopsis
>
> **timeout** *[OPTION] NUMBER[SUFFIX] COMMAND [ARG]...*
>   **timeout** *[OPTION]*
>
> ---
>
> ### Description
>
> Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after NUMBER seconds. SUFFIX may be 's' for seconds (the default), 'm' for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for days.
>
> **-s**, **--signal**=*SIGNAL*
>   specify the signal to be sent on timeout.
>           *SIGNAL* may be a name like 'HUP' or a number.
>           See 'kill -l' for a list of signals

By depending on `timeout`, you don't have to worry about the messy details of PID reuse, race conditions, etc. Those concerns are nicely encapsulated in this standard Unix utility. Another benefit is your script will resume execution immediately upon early termination by the subprocess, rather than needlessly sleeping for the full 10 seconds.

Demo in bash:

```
timeout -s9 10 sleep 11; echo $?;
## Killed
## 137
timeout -s9 10 sleep 3; echo $?;
## 0
```

Demo in python:

```
import subprocess;
subprocess.Popen(['timeout','-s9','10','sleep','11']).wait();
## -9
subprocess.Popen(['timeout','-s9','10','sleep','3']).wait();
## 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be useful. In this case, I would prefer a native python solution. Thanks anyway for `timeout` introduction :)

Answer (score -3):

I am using command stop process_name on ubuntu for stop my process.
May it will helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I need a solution which works for all linux distros. I said that the script is run as root, so I do not understand the `sudo` here. And finally, the process name is bash so I cannot kill it by name.